# Merging word documents in VBA EXCEL (issue: reversed order)

Tags: excel, wordpress, vba

In EXCEL, I am combining a few word documents using VBA. My work flow is:

1. Open an template and remove all the existing text (only keep the format_
2. start a loop by copying each word document to be combined (I will copy from Line 13 of each file)
3. paste into the merged file

So far most of the steps are good except that the merged file is in revers order, which means the last page of the combined document actually is the first opened document. Is there a way to paste text in the normal order? Thanks!

```
Set newDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(path to template)
'clear template text in this template
objWord.Selection.WholeStory
objWord.Selection.Delete

For i = 1 To NoOfFiles
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Folderpath to output files)
        ' goto line 13
        Set r = objDoc.Goto(what:=3, which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=13)
        r.End = objDoc.Range.End
        r.Copy
        newDoc.Content.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
        newDoc.Range(newDoc.Content.Start, newDoc.Content.Start).Paste

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Your range you are pasting into is the start of the document (newDoc.Content.Start).  Maybe try newDoc.Content.End?

Comment: @leowyn, I tried `newDoc.Range(newDoc.Content.End, newDoc.Content.Start).Paste` but got `value out of range` error

Comment: the two parameters passed to Range are the start and end cursor positions.  If you use `newDoc.Range(newDoc.Content.End, newDoc.Content.Start).Paste` then you are trying to create range that goes backwards from the end of the document to the start of it.  Try `newDoc.Range(newDoc.Content.End, newDoc.Content.End).Paste`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried `newDoc.Range(newDoc.Content.End, newDoc.Content.End).Paste` but same `out of range` error

Comment: This page might have what you need (see the last example): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220332(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @leowyn, thanks for the reference! I ended up with looping reversely for now.

Answer (score 0):

This script will merge all Word files into one.

```
Sub MergeAllWordDocs1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyName As String, MyPath As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Documents.Add
    MyPath = "C:\Users\your_path_here\" ' <= change this as necessary
    MyName = Dir$(MyPath & "*.do*") ' not *.* if you just want doc files
    Do While MyName <> ""
        If InStr(MyName, "~") = 0 Then
            Selection.InsertFile _
    FileName:="""" & MyPath & MyName & """",
            ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False,
            Attachment:=False
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
  End If
        MyName = Dir() ' gets the next doc file in the directory
    Loop
End Sub
```